# Cannot install cmake on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, cmake

I'm having issues getting cmake installed onto my machine. Here is what I am running:

```
sudo apt-get -f install cmake
```

And here is the output:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cmake : Depends: libjsoncpp1 but it is not installable
```

I have tried running apt-get update but it doesn't seem to help. Please let me know what I should try. Would be happy to provide more information.

Thanks! :)

Edit: The output of "apt-cache policy cmake" is as follows:

```
    cmake:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.5.2-2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1~ppa1
  Version table:
     3.5.2-2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1~ppa1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas-schiex/blender/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     3.2.2-2~ubuntu14.04.1~ppa1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/george-edison55/cmake-3.x/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     2.8.12.2-0ubuntu3 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Thanks!

Update: Thanks! I was able to install cmake. However, I can't seem to make anything with it. I'm running

```
cmake ../
```

in an empty directory which I created inside the project I'm trying to make. Here is the output:

```
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
/usr/bin
CMake Error: Error executing cmake::LoadCache(). Aborting.
```

Would anybody have any idea on what to do next? I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling as well as apt-get update. Again, I can post more information on here if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: You must have made some unusual changes to your sources.list* files, as **libjsoncpp1** is only available for Xenial and later (refer  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libjsoncpp1&searchon=names).  That package is not a requirement for Trusty's [14.04] version of `cmake`  (refer https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/cmake-curses-gui & https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/cmake)

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy cmake`? On normal Trusty `cmake` installs normally, you have PPA or third-party repositories.

Comment: @N0rbert I add the output to the question - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install cmake from `main` repository by specifying its version:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake=2.8.12.2-0ubuntu3
```

If it fails, try one of the following methods:

- remove PPAs from system with their packages and then install version from `main` repository

  ```
  sudo ppa-purge ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
  sudo ppa-purge ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
  sudo apt-get install cmake
  ```
- temporary disable PPAs, install `cmake` then enable PPAs:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install cmake
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
  ```

Then you can try to build simple cmake example. Fast googling gave me the [cmake-example.git](https://github.com/bast/cmake-example) repository. I do not know what is this, but it compiles fast and runs normally:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake git build-essential gfortran
git clone https://github.com/bast/cmake-example.git
cd cmake-example/
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

You can test it by executing compiled programs:

```
./hello.x
./main.x
./unit_tests
```

If it fails then you have other problems in your system.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to install cmake version 2.8 but now I'm having problems using it...I will update my post.

Comment: I updated my answer - added cmake-example.

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert - I had already cloned the repository I wanted to make, but I didn't have build-essential gfortran installed. I tried installing gfortran and running cmake but I got the same error as before. Do I need to clone the repository again?

Answer (score 0):

Cmake 3.16.5 installation from sources for Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.10:

- `wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.16.5/cmake-3.16.5.tar.gz`
- `tar vxzv cmake-3.16.5.tar.gz`
- `cd cmake-3.16.5`
- `./bootstrap`
- `make`
- `sudo make install`

I have two `cmake` versions installed on my Ubuntu 18.04 VM:

```
whereis cmake
cmake: /usr/bin/cmake /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake /usr/local/bin/cmake /usr/share/cmake /usr/share/man/man1/cmake.1.gz

user@u1804:~$ /usr/local/bin/cmake --version
cmake version 3.16.5

user@u1804:~$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.16.5

user@u1804:~$ /usr/bin/cmake --version
cmake version 3.10.2
```

Older version of `cmake` have been installed by `sudo apt install cmake`.

But current the latest stable release of cmake 3.16.5 could also be installed using `snap`:

```
sudo snap install cmake
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an [unofficial repository](https://launchpad.net/~mantid/+archive/ubuntu/mantid) that has a version for 14.04.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mantid/mantid
sudo apt-get update
```